# How to setup a project with React Typescript app and a runnable server side script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a project with a React Typescript app (created with Create React App). I would like to have an executable script in this same project that I can run. Both the app and the script will only run on local machines.

The script and React app depend on the same Typescript module which is a single ts file called `algorithm.ts`. I would like to be able to do something like this in the CLI:

- `npm start` --> runs the React App
- `npm run myscript` --> runs the script

I have tried multiple things, the most recent effort is to have the script be a nodejs script and compile the algorithm from Typescript to JS everytime before running the script with node. However, this ends up in the following error when running the script:

```
$ npm run myscript

> tsc src/algorithm.ts && node src/myscript.js

file:///<path>/src/algorithm.js:2
exports.__esModule = true;
^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at file:///<path>/src/algorithm.js:2:1
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:146:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:165:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

This also forces the script to be JS instead of Typescript, which I wouldn't prefer, but I guess I can live with.

Here are the relevant files:

#### `algorithm.ts`:

```
import { blabla } from "blabla";
...
export const function1 = ...
export const function2 = ...
...
```

#### `ReactComponent.tsx`:

```
import { function1, function2 } from "./algorithm";
...
```

#### `myscript.js`:

```
import * as algorithm from "algorithm.js"
...
```

#### package.json:

```
...
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "myscript": "tsc src/algorithm.ts && node src/myscript.js"
  },
...
```

#### `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. The problem was that the `tsc src/algorithm.ts` command was compiling the file using CommonJS instead of ESModules. To fix it, I created a second `tsconfig.json` file with:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016", 
    "module": "esnext", 
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  },
  "files": [
    "../src/algorithm.ts"
  ]
}
```

and changed the script command in `package.json` to use this tsconfig file `"myscript": "tsc -p scripts/tsconfig.json && node src/myscript.js"`

I still have no idea if all this is overkill and there is an easier way to achieve what I want, so won't mark it as accepted answer. But at least it works!